# jQuery Document Ready Function not Working

Tags: jquery, html, document, onload, ready

I've been trying to get a page to open a lightwindow when it's done loading using jQuery's `document.ready` function and I cannot figure out why it won't work...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="">
<meta http-equiv="ImageToolbar" content="No">


<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<!-- Jquery -->            
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>



<!-- add lightwindow stuff -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightwindow.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightwindow.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<!-- finish adding lightwindow stuff -->

<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />






<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
 font-size: 16px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $myLightWindow.activateWindow({
   href: 'http://website.com', 
   title: 'website',
    });
$(document).ready(myLightWindow);

</script>

</head>

<body>
```

I have links in the page and have verified that the lightwindow works with external sites. the lightwindow was sourced from here: http://www.p51labs.com/lightwindow/#configure

Thanks -

Brandon

Comment: What are `$myLightWindow` and `myLightWindow`? If defined in external script, then post relevant code in question. Anyway, you have to provide relevant code in question, your code snippet is useless without the relevant external scripts

Comment: Hello A. Wolff, sorry this is my first question :). $myLightWindow is the function held in the lightwindow.js script that can be called and the .activatewindow function is what is supposed to load a refrenced external page in an  iframe :)

Comment: ok i inspected the page in chrome and it says undefined () is not a function, should I set the function "$myLightWindow" as a function?

Answer (score 2):

You're not creating a function, you're calling the function. Use the `ready` function with a callback and do the window activation in there.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $myLightWindow.activateWindow({
        href: 'http://website.com', 
        title: 'website',
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I just tried this and it's still not loading, would it be an issue with the document.ready function being stopped by an iframe I embedded in the page? also another alternative I have tried is the <body onLoad="LoadMyJs()"> function...

Answer (score 0):

ok I think i found that a function was conflicting with the jQuery document.ready function. I called jquery with a test script.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>






<script type="text/javascript">
    ( function($) {
     // rely on $ within safety of "bodyguard" function
        $(document).ready( function() { alert("jquery functioning");  } );
    } ) ( jQuery );

    
    </script>
```

and got it to tell me jquery is functioning...